# Java algorithm to work out time using distance and time?

Tags: java

I'm looking for an implementation in Java using a method for:

```
time = distance / speed
```

Time in minutes

Distance in metres

Speed in kilometres per hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure the `time` t, taken to reach a `distance` d with a `speed` of v,

then

```
// time = distance / speed
t = d / v units_of_time
```

For a distance of `60 miles`, if you are driving at a speed of `40 mph` then

```
t = 60 / 40 
t = 1.5 hours
```

**Java Solution**:

```
long distance = 60; // kilometers
double speed = 40.0d; // kmph

double speed_in_meters_per_minute = ( speed * 1000 ) / 60; // mpm

// now calculate time in minutes
double time = (double)distance / speed_in_meters_per_minute ;
```

You can round of time value to a desired precision and scale.

Comment: Using Java integer division the answer would be 1 hour and not 1.5 hours. You'd need to cast at least one value to double or float.

Comment: @Squonk: Come on. It is just a path for solution. Not an exact `JAVA` solution.

Comment: The question has a Java tag on it. Other programming languages might work with `60 / 40` using variant types but Java won't. It's not as if I downvoted you or anything - I was simply making a point. If you answer a question which is directly related to a programming language then give an accurate answer.

Comment: @Squonk: Yes. I saw that too. Updated my answer with a java solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Rate*Time=Distance. So, once you have figure out that distance, just take that, divide it by what ever speed the user entered, and Viola!

Pseudo code:

```
TimeToTravel = DistanceBetweenPoints / TimeUserEntered
```

Helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Distance = Rate * Time

Div both sides by Rate:

Time = Distance / Rate (Speed)

Answer (score 0):

speed = distance / time

Therefore:

time = distance / speed

Answer (score 0):

distance in 2d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1))

then its just distance over time

v = d/t